# empty matches in regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

i'm trying to understand some simple code from Python doc

```
>>> p = re.compile('x*')
>>> p.sub('-', 'abxd')
'-a-b-d-'
```

in the doc they say: "Empty matches are replaced only when they’re not adjacent to a previous match."
but i just can't understand why the result is not 'ab-d'

thanks

edit - this is the link to the doc i read: "https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*` is a meta character and that means that, *match 0 or more times*. So, in this case,

1. before `a` it finds 0 `x`
2. before `b` it finds 0 `x`
3. before `d` it finds 1 `x`
4. finally it finds 0 `x` after `d`.

That is why it replaces all the occurances of `x` (including the zero occurences) with `-`.

If you want to have the result as `ab-d`, then use `+` metacharacter, which means that *match 1 or more times*. So it will only find the `x` before `d` and it will replace only that.

Comment: i just don't understand why between a and b it put '-'
there is nothing between them...

Comment: @asafel Exactly. Since there is nothing in between them, it matches `x` 0 times

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself the question, how many empty matches are between `a` and `b`. An infinite number. But once the empty space is replaced by `-` there are no more matches.

Answer (score 0):

Use `x+` instead of `x*`

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile('x*')
>>> p.sub('-', 'abxd')
'-a-b-d-'
>>> p = re.compile('x+')
>>> p.sub('-', 'abxd')
'ab-d'
>>>
```

Note: `*` will match 0 or more occurrence of the character(s) and `+` will match 1 or occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

If there if only one `x` present in your input then no need for `+` after `x` in the pattern .

```
>>> re.sub(r'x', r'-', 'abxd')
'ab-d'
```