# why it returns match like that

Tags: javascript, regex

I tested code below:

```
var str1 = 'chapter 4.5.3.1'
var rslt = str1.match(/(\.\d)*/g)
console.log(rslt)
```

and it returns me matchs of

```
["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ".5.3.1", ""]
```

if I goes

```
var str1 = 'chapter 4.5.3.1'
var rslt = str1.match(/(\.\d)*/)
console.log(rslt)
```

and it gives me:

```
["", undefined, index: 0, input: "chapter 4.5.3.1"]
```

could somebody explain those match result to me, especially the 1st example, why there are so many empty string is returned. And the 2nd match, there is an empty string retuned. Thank you.

Comment: Think about it: Does `a*` match the input `b`? Where?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25152849/empty-matches-in-regular-expressions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`*` repeats the preceding token zero or more times. When you use the global flag along with the regex, you get an empty string as match for each character except the characters which matches the pattern. If you remove the global flag, it matches the empty string at the first only, because the regex engine stops matching after the first match. So that only you get a single empty string as match while after removing the `g` flag.

Answer (score 4):

`(\.\d)*` actually means that, match the group `(\.\d)` **zero or more times**. Since the match is available zero times, before every character, it returns an empty string for all the zero matches. You have to change it to `(\.\d)+`, which means match the group **one or more times**.

If you actually want to match only the version numbers, then you can use

```
/\d+(\.\d+)*/
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case there are empty strings returned because you are using the `*` quantifier (0 or more) instead of the `+` quantifier (1 or more).

Your pattern is therefore allowed to match the empty string *and so it does*, multiple times.  Note that the number of empty strings in the result prior to the first non-empty match is 9, the same number of characters until the first match of more than zero characters.  This is because the regular expression matches the empty string at each position.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to capture just the numeric value something along these lines should work.

\d*(.\d)*(?=[^\d]|$)

The * can be a tricky beast.